# Cannot Start Mysql On My WHM Server

Tags: mysql

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
MySQL manager or server process #6292 is not running!      [FAILED]
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/mysql/ns1.iglobalsolution.co.id.pid': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove `/var/lock/subsys/mysql': Read-only file system
Failed to stop running server, so refusing to try to start.[FAILED]
```

Help me please!!

Because i don't understand why this error my whm

Answer (score 1):

Like the error messages says, your filesystem is read-only. This is usually the result of a hard drive failure. Contact your hosting provider.

I hope you have backups.

Comment: I have User ROOT for login access to my WHM

Comment: That's irrelevant. **Your server's hard disk is probably failing.** It doesn't care about your root access.

Comment: How to solution for my serve ? Reinstall ?

Comment: Contact your hosting provider. This is not a problem you can solve remotely.

Comment: Hosting Provider on me , , ,my Hosting Provider